# Join two csv + first File fist colum + second file first column and take only match column data

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, join

file1.txt

```
name
abc
xyz
pqr
```

file2.txt

```
name,addr,id
abc,hj,1
pqr,hj.2
jkd,hj,9
jh,jd,2
```

output file

```
name,addr,id
abc,hj,1
pqr,hj.2
```

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange, please take the time to read the [tour]. Question on stackexchange should try to explain the main goal, show if possible an example of what you have and what you want and more than that a proof of work. We are not here to do your job but to help you. Also file 2 = output here, so your phrasing doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

use `join`:

```
join -t, -o 0,1.2,1.3 <(sort <(tail -n +2 file2)) <(sort <(tail -n +2 file1))
abc,hj,1
pqr,hj,2
```

- `-t,` specify input/output fields separator as a *comma*.
- `-o` output only specified fields; `0` is the join (first) field (can be replaced with `1.1` or `2.1`); the format is `X.Y` (which field `Y` from which file `X`.)
- `tail -n +2 infile` return all lines except the first *header* line.
- `sort ...` sorts each input files.

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {!seen[$1]; next} $1 in seen' file1 file2
name,addr,id
abc,hj,1
pqr,hj,2
```

- `-F,` specify input fields separator is a *comma*.
- `NR==FNR`; `NR` will set to 1 on first record/line read by *awk* and incrementing until all records/lines read either if single input file or multiple files; `FNR` will set to 1 on first record/line read by *awk* and incrementing until all records/lines read in current input file and will reset back to 1 for the next file; so `NR==FNR` will be true only when *awk* is reading first `file1` input file and its following block will be executed. which is creating an associated array called `seen` with the lines in *file1* as Indexes of that array if it is not previously set.
- `$1 in seen`: this executing on second `file2` only and checks if first column in that file matched with any key in array `seen` then it will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```bsh
grep --color=never -f <(cut -d, -f1 file1.txt | sed 's#.*#^\0,#') file2.txt
```

Explanation:

- `grep -f`: Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per line
- `--color=never` (optional) removes color from `grep` output for the matches.
- `<([...])`  is the syntax for  creating a file descriptor based on the content in between the brackets which is as follows:
- `cut -d, -f1 file1.txt` will return the first column of file1.txt
- `sed 's#.*#^\0,#'` will make the first column read like `^column1,` for creating the correct pattern for `grep`.

if you want to exclude the headers to avoid errors (not necessary in your example), use this :

```bsh
head -n 1 file2.txt && \
grep --color=never -f <(tail -n +2 file1.txt | cut -d, -f1 | sed 's#.*#^\0,#') file2.txt
```

Both commands return:

```
name,addr,id
abc,hj,1
pqr,hj.2
```